# LM337 voltage regulator outputs different voltage than calculated

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am using an LM337 to keep voltage stable at 3V from a battery supply (4x AAA). I've calculated R1 and R2 from the formula to be **100 Ohms** and **140 Ohms** respectively:

```
Vo = -1.25*(1+R2/R1)
Vo = -1.25*(1+140/100)
Vo = -1.25*(1+1.4)
Vo = -3
```

And I used **1uF solid tantulum** and **10uF electrolytic** capacitors.

Yet it gives me about 4.5V output. Did I screw up something?

[image: Image from LM337 docs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers seem correct, as do the capacitors. Check the regulator pinout that you are using (it is different from similar positive regulators) and double check the resistor values if the pinout is correct.

---

Edit: since it appears you would be better served by a positive regulator, I suggest you do a parametric search at a distributor or series of manufacturers. Many parameters are important and modern LDO regulators tend to be much more specialized in terms of a combination of max input voltage, current (quiescent, max), power dissipation, package type, max and min output current and so on.

Just for example, the [LP3869](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp38691-adj.pdf) but there are thousands of possibilities so chances are it will be sub-optimal in some way.

Comment: Well LM317 seems to be:
1. Adjust 2. Out 3. In
However the docs for LM337 shows:
1. Adjust 2. In 3. Out

Is there a way to test it?

Comment: You are testing it- measure the voltages especially the voltage from Vo to adj and the input voltage.

Comment: In the docs they are talking about negative voltage. I thought I would hook it up to a battery and get a steady voltage of 3V but it seems to take negative voltage and give stable negative voltage. Since I am providing positive voltage could it be the problem? I perhaps need to buy the LM317 which seems to operate on positive voltage.

Comment: Ah, you need to give it negative voltage for sure. Since you have a battery, just connect it appropriately. Assuming you have not damaged the regulator it should work.

Comment: Yes, the LM337 is a **negative** voltage regulator.  So it works with an input that is **negative** with respect to circuit common, and puts out a voltage that is **negative** with respect to circuit common.  If that's too much negativity, then yes, you need an LM317.

Comment: LM317 etc are more common and cheaper than negative regulators, but search for a better one for battery use, those old regulators wast a lot of power which drains the batteries (12-13mA quiescent draw in your case)

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion which one would be better? I really don't know what to look for. I just want regulator with low dropout. So I can keep 3V even when the battery voltage gets close to the 3V. Also if you want some points, post it as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer.